# How to detect if an ESP32 is connected to a computer with code?

Tags: c++, serial-port, esp32

Let me explain. I am using an ESP32 in a project and there are some triggers, but the consequence of the triggers has to depend on if the ESP32 is connected to the computer or not. More specifically, if there is a Serial Monitor in connection to the ESP32.
So, is there a way to see this through code?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Short of the other end of the serial connection sending messages down to the ESP32, nope. Serial ports are really, really dumb. There's generally no way to tell if a quiet connection is there are not. Somebody has to start wiggling pins first.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks! I'll just put a switch that symbolizes the chip being connected to the computer. Can you put that in an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: You could check for 5V to at least distinguish between a USB Mass Storage Device and a PC.